# How to remove link property when click on the link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working code. What I want is when user click promo code link, the link property will be removed and will be non functional anymore. This is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/5DbN3/

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
      text.innerHTML = "Have a promo code?";
    }
    else {
      ele.style.display = "block";
      text.innerHTML = "Have a promo code?";
    }
  } 
</script>

<h1>GET STARTED</h1>
<form action="http://www....." method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <label for="zipcode">
    <h2>Enter your zip code:</h2>
    </strong>
  </label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" maxlength="5"/>
  </div>
  <label for="promocode">
    <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Have a promo code?</a>
  </label>
  <div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" name="promocode" id="promocode"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="zipsubmit" value="GO" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean by "link property"? Also, using javascript call as an href is pretty old school; you're using jQuery already so perhaps looking into `.on()` for binding event handlers? I suspect that inside your `.on()` function you'll be able to control what a click means to a particular element if that's what you're gunning for.

Comment: Just noticed this while re-indenting your code for you-- `<h2>` inside a label is invalid markup, and you have a closing `</strong>` tag that doesn't match an opening tag. You can use CSS to style elements properly instead of trying to make it "bigger and bolder" with an h2 element.

Comment: What I mean is when user clicks have a promo code? which is link, the textbox will appear below which is like that now, and that 'Have a promode code' text will be regular text instead of a link. Therefore, when user click on it again, the promocode textbox won't disappear again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
.removeAttribute("href");
```

or in jQuery

```
.removeAttr("href");
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5DbN3/1/

Comment: Thanks for that, Alex. I was willing to provide a whole .on() example, not knowing that an anchor without an href would just become "unclickable" (losing the styling and everything). Glad to learn new things!